# Upgrade symfony 2.8 or php 5.4 first?

Tags: upgrade, symfony-3.4, symfony-2.8, php-5.4, php-7.2

I'll be working soon on a project and I just wanted to ask this before.
The project is on symfony 2.8 with php 5.4.
The goal is to upgrade symfony to 3.4 (maybe 4.x later) and php to 7.x (probably 7.2).
So here is my question : is there a better order to do this?
Php 5.4 to 7.2  first or symfony 2.8 to 3.4 (or it doesn't matter)?
Thanks for your advices.

Comment: You can automate lots of changes with Rector, for Symfony instant upgrade: https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/tree/master/config/level/symfony, and PHP as well:  https://github.com/rectorphp/rector/tree/master/config/level/php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all – you won't be able to run Symfony 3.4 project on PHP5.4.

**As of 2018-11-26**

The latest Symfony ^3.4 version is `v3.4.19` which requires `php: ^5.5.9|>=7.0.8`.

On the other hand latest Symfony ^2.8 version is `v2.8.48` which requires `php: >=5.3.9`.

*Conclusion*

You won't be able to run Symfony 3.4 project on PHP 5.4, but in theory you will be able to run Symfony 2.8 project with PHP 7.2.

You should also consider taking a look at:
http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php

Comment: @BorisFournier I missmatched some versions in conclusion – please re-read.

Comment: don't worry, that was what I understood anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go **with PHP first** as long as Symfony allows you to. It's much easier to follow changes in PHP code then changes in big PHP framework.

The best way is to use an instant upgrade with [Rector](https://getrector.org/) (a tool I wrote):

```
vendor/bin/rector process src --level php53
vendor/bin/rector process src --level php54
vendor/bin/rector process src --level symfony30
vendor/bin/rector process src --level php55
vendor/bin/rector process src --level symfony31
vendor/bin/rector process src --level php56
vendor/bin/rector process src --level symfony32
vendor/bin/rector process src --level php70
vendor/bin/rector process src --level php71
vendor/bin/rector process src --level symfony33
vendor/bin/rector process src --level symfony34
```

Always **one minore version** at a time.

---

I summed my experience with many upgraded websites in this post: [How to Upgrade Symfony 2.8 to 3.4](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2019/02/28/how-to-upgrade-symfony-2-8-to-3-4/)